# BeautifulSoup get p contents from a div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the content of p tags from a webpage. The way it's structured is like this

```
<div property="pas:description">
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
</div>
```

I don't just want to use getText() because there's other content on the page I don't want. I've looked through documentation, but I'm still not sure how to to get the content from the p tags here

EDIT: I don't want to get all content from p tags, as there's other content in p tags on this page. I specifically only want to get the content that's in a div with the property 'pas:description'

Comment: check the answer , if it completes the requirements than please accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
soup.find('div', {'property': "pas:description"})
```

to find `div` with `property` and later you can search `p` inside this `div`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

text = '''<p>without div 1</p>
<div property="pas:description">
  <p>content 1</p>
  <p>content 2</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>content in div without property </p>
</div>
<p>without div 2</p>'''

soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')

div = soup.find('div', {'property': "pas:description"})

for p in div.find_all('p'):
    print(p.string)
```

Result

```
content 1
content 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is code for extracting "content"

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

test_html= '''
            <div property="pas:description">
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            </div>
           ''' 
soup4 = BeautifulSoup(test_html, 'html.parser')

print(soup4.find('div').p.text)
```